# Drop keyspace is not working

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying use Datastax Enterprise for deploying database system

My cluster:

- 2 dse cassandra node
- 2 dse solr node

I created a keyspace by `cqlsh` on one node but I could not drop that keyspace from another nodes on cluster, unless drop from node creating keyspace. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5202

I have had to delete the data directory for the troubled key space in all nodes and restart DSE to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the output from cqlsh on the node that won't allow you to drop the keyspace? 
What version of DSE are you using?

Comment: nothing output is showed, seem the command complete but the keyspace still exist

Comment: Could you give me the following :  
  
 - DSE Version you are using
 - create keyspace command 
 - Output of dsetool ring 
 - using cassandra-cli the output of "describe cluster"

Comment: Also you may want to turn ton tracing in the cqlsh shell if your version of DSE supports it. Just type:  
TRACING ON  
And try that from the node you created the keyspace on and another node.